# ruby on rails, heroku push error: "rake aborted", "Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am new to ruby, and is following some guide on first deploy of a website. I find it difficult to follow exactly what the author said since it has been written for quite a while.

Here is what happens after I typed in `git push heroku master`

```
Counting objects: 68, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (68/68), 17.29 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 68 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.6
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.5
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.3.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.23
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 1.3.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.0
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.5
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.7
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.5
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.0.0
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.5
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.5
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.5
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.5
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.5
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.5
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.0
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.5
remote:        Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (23.25s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
remote: sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'.
remote:  !     Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Sass::Script
remote:  !     Backtrace for gem load error is:
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.0/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.0/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.0/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.0/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.0/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Bundler Error Backtrace:
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_58ad731988b51b7dabe8f6a61971228c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
......
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/ruby_compile:11:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to hidden-eyrie-90646.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/hidden-eyrie-90646.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hidden-eyrie-90646.git'

But when I typed in the command  `$ bundle install --without production`
It seems alright:
`Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using rake 12.0.0
Using i18n 0.8.1
Using json 1.8.6
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 1.6.5
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.4
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.4
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using rack-timeout 0.3.2
Using bundler 1.14.4
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using sass 3.4.23
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
Using nokogiri 1.7.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using uglifier 1.3.0
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 4.2.5
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.7
Using activemodel 4.2.5
Using jbuilder 2.0.0
Using spring 2.0.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
Using activejob 4.2.5
Using activerecord 4.2.5
Using actionview 4.2.5
Using actionpack 4.2.5
Using actionmailer 4.2.5
Using railties 4.2.5
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
Using rails 4.2.5
Using sass-rails 5.0.0
Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 53 gems now installed.
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.`
```

(I deleted some message because it exceeded the length limit of stackoverflow.)

My Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]

# Use postgresql as database for production
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', ' 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', ' 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', ' 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', ' 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', ' 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'spring', group: :development

gem 'rack-timeout', '0.3.2'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', ' 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

#group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
#  gem 'byebug'
#end

#group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
#  gem 'web-console', ' 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
#  gem 'spring'
#end
```

My Gemfile is not the same as the lecturer presented, because somehow I can't install the 4.1.0 version Ruby (mine is 4.2.5) on Cloud9 IDE.
And here is the lecturer's Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]

# Use postgresql as database for production
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', ' 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', ' 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', ' 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', ' 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', ' 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'spring', group: :development
```

What should I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your gem version is

```
gem 'sass-rails', ' 5.0'
```

change it to

```
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.3' or gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.2'
```

or do

```
bundle update sass-rails
```

which ultimately updates you saas-rails gem to the latest one. Or you can enter the version in your gemfile as specified above.

Comment: in heroku logs : there is  
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: After I committed, I pushed again, the error message change into
`remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant Uglifier::VERSION
........
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to hidden-eyrie-90646.`

Comment: can you please try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338860/heroku-push-error-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-uglifierversion-on-rake

I think this will work.

Comment: Thanks dude  for voting up :)